# Javascript replace method avoiding copy-paste

Tags: javascript, replace

I am creating a textarea with a div next to it.
There are keyword that will display HTML elements in the div to see how you format your document. (Like Title, Content, Section, Code, and so on...)

As there are many keywords, is there any possibility to simplify and shorten a replace method, replacing **different** keywords to **different** strings?

Under that I mean:

```
document.getElementById("example").value.replace(/example1/gi,"something1")
                                 .replace(/example2/gi,"something2")
                                 .replace(/example3/gi,"something3")
                                 ...;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create array of rules and iterate through it:

```
const val = document.getElementById("example").value;
const regExp = [["ex1","sm1"],["ex2","sm2"],["ex3","sm3"]];
regExp.forEach(replace => val = val.replace(new RegExp(replace[0],'ig'),replace[1]));
```